# Extracting data from increasing, multi-concentric buffers around each focal point in a vector layer

Tags: qgis, point, vector-layer, buffer

I have a dataset (vector layer) with 150 focal points, each of them retaining an observation of several ecological variables (attributes). I want to extract data (sum and average of several variables) from increasing multi-concentric rings around each focal points (same radii for all points). For example, I want to start with radius=1 Km around all the points and get a table showing new values calculated over the buffer coverage. Then, I want to increase the radius to 5 Km, 10 Km, 50 Km, 100 Km, to get the relevant datasets.
(Eventually, I will have to perform more complex, separate statistical analyses from these tables).
Would it be possible by using QGIS?
I am new of GIS softwares and I have no idea how to handle this.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Yes, everything you're asking about is possible with QGIS. See this link for information about buffers: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html. You can use **spatial joins** to connect data from the points layer with the buffer layers. The **field calculator** will be helpful in making various calculations.